# How to Split the_content() and store into array in wordpress where <!--nextpage-->

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to split the `the_content()` function in Wordpress where `<!--nextpage-->`and store it into array, I am trying to achieve this without using plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than use `the_content()` (that would print the content directly on the page), you can use `get_the_content()` and then split it from there:

```
$parts = explode('<!--nextpage-->', get_the_content());
```

Comment: This is elegant - I like it. Introducing comments doesn't affect anything and it's an easy way to demarcate in the editor where you want breaks to happen. Cool!

Answer (score 2):

Just use the function [`get_the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/) (the content will echo it, get_ functions will not) and explode it like this:

```
$content = get_the_content();
list($page, $nextpage) = explode('<!--nextpage-->', $content);

// or when $content has more than one "<!--nextpage-->"
$pages = explode('<!--nextpage-->', $content);
```